# unexpected references to same object in different instances (python)

Tags: python, inheritance, reference

Some code I have a problem with:

```
# a connector
class conn():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

# a device base class
class imper_dev():
    names = []
    conns = {}
    def __init__(self):
        for name in self.names:
            self.conns[name] = conn(name)

# a real device          
class dev(imper_dev):   
    names = ['a']       

# some instances of it               
d1 = dev()              
d2 = dev()              

>>> d1.conns['a']
<__main__.conn object at 0x7fd68871c630>      
>>> d2.conns['a'] 
<__main__.conn object at 0x7fd68871c630>
```

I am a little surprised by this behavior. My intention is to create instances of `dev()` with independent connectors. Why have both instances `d1` and `d2` the same reference for `conns['a']`?

Comment: Have a look at [static variables in a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`conns` is a [class variable](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) which means that variable is shared between all instances of the `dev` class.
Note that `d1` and `d2` are actually different objects, it's only `conns` and `names` that are shared here.

```
>>> d1
<__main__.dev instance at 0x7fb757329050>
>>> d2
<__main__.dev instance at 0x7fb7573290e0>
```